# Как не прерывая Flow вызвать долгую по времени выполнения suspend функцию?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

Я пытаюсь разобраться в принципах работы с Kotlin Coroutines. У меня есть список передаваемый через `Flow` в `Viewmodel`.

```
val chatsFlow = chatsChangedFlow.asSharedFlow()
    .map {
        chatList.map { chat ->
            Chat(
                id = chat.id,
                title = chat.title,
                photo = chat.photo?.let {
                    val photoFilePath = downloadFile(it.file)
                    
                    ProfilePhoto(
                        thumbnail = it.thumbnail.data,
                        filePath = photoFilePath
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

И каждый раз при вызове `downloadFile` `Flow` дожидается возврата значения, лишь после этого идёт на следующую итерацию.

Можно ли добиться в данном случае поведения чтоб при вызове `downloadFile` поле `filePath` оставалось неинициализированным и лишь после обработки значения через некоторое время заполнялось тем самым не прерывая работы `Flow`?

P.S. `downloadFile` тоже suspend функция на основе `suspendCancellableCoroutine`

Answer (score 0):

```
И каждый раз при вызове downloadFile Flow дожидается возврата значения, лишь после этого идёт на следующую итерацию.
```

Да и это нормально. Ситуация, когда "скорость обработки значений ниже, чем скорость эмитирования новых данных" корректируется через Стратегии переполнения буфера через метод `.buffer()`
но что-то подсказывает, что вам это не поможет. вы лишь упустите часть новых данных.

```
при вызове downloadFile поле filePath оставалось неинициализированным и лишь после обработки значения
```

для этого в корутинах можно запускать дочерние корутины `launch` или `async`
`async` возвращает тип `Deffered` - это нейкая работа, результат который вы можете долждаться и получить вызвав на ней `.await()`

возможно стоить сделать `filePath` именно типа `Deffered<String>`, но это не точно.

UPD
отбой =(
внутри .map нельзя вызвать `async` и из suspend функций нельзя вернуть незаконченные `Deferred`

UPD 2.0
именно, что из suspend нельзя, но никто не мешает сделать обычный метод, который будет возвращать Deferred!

```
 fun downloadFile() : Deferred<String> = viewModelScope.async { 
            delay(3000)
            "hello world"
        }
```

Comment: Если я буду вызывать photoFilePath.await() то будет то же поведение. Так как данный код вызывается внутри map то у меня каждая итерация map ждёт получения значения await. И получается что в моем приложении список появляется по 1 элементу с задержкой в пару секунд)

Comment: @xephosbot измени модель filePath было Deferred<String> и запустите выполенение асинхронного async